# I am getting java Heap Space Error while building my workspace any solutions?

Tags: eclipse

I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error in eclipse whenever i try to build my workspace i have tried many memory specifications but none work plz help the following is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
--vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javaw.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify --launcher.XXMaxPermSize twice, you might want to remove the second one.  Also, your last line you should remove " -vmargs ..." on, it must be one argument per line.  And I'm pretty sure the runtime argument is just "-vm" not "--vm", and it must be before -vmargs.

PW